# 'no empty constructor' logcat error when creating list with a custom adapter

Tags: java, android, list, constructor

I'm trying to populate a list using a custom adapter, however when I try and run the app it just crashes. Checking my logcat I get this error:

```
03-11 15:33:59.695: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 15:33:59.695: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): Process: com.example.task2_final, PID: 1200
03-11 15:33:59.695: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.task2_final/com.example.task2_final.Bike}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.task2_final.Bike; no empty constructor
03-11 15:33:59.695: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
03-11 15:33:59.695: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
```

Here is my Bike.java class:

```
package com.example.task2_final;


public class Bike {

    private String title;
    private String imageName;


    //Constructor
    Bike (String title,  String imageName) {
        this.title= title;
        this.imageName = imageName;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setImage(String imageName){
        this.imageName = imageName;
    }   
    public String getBikeTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public String getBikeImageName(){
        return imageName;
    }



}
```

And here is my AndroidManifest.xml if it's needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.task2_final"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Bike"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

New error after constructor was added:

```
03-11 15:42:21.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 15:42:21.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): Process: com.example.task2_final, PID: 1247
03-11 15:42:21.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.task2_final/com.example.task2_final.Bike}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to constructor not allowed
```

UseCustomAdapter.java

```
package com.example.task2_final;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UseCustomAdapter extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<Bike> bikes = new ArrayList<Bike>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        bikes.add(new Bike("Honda", "honda"));
        bikes.add(new Bike("Suzuki", "suzuki"));
        bikes.add(new Bike("Kawasaki", "kawasaki"));
        bikes.add(new Bike("KTM", "ktm"));
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, bikes);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Bike b = bikes.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(this,"You selected the " + b.getBikeTitle()
                + "Motocross Bike",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just add an empty constructor for Bike. Something like `Bike (){}`

Comment: Have you read the error completely before posting to Stack , it is clearly stating that you don't have a default constructor in Bike Class

Comment: Have you tried adding an empty constructor?

Comment: Yes sorry if this seemed ridiculous but under //Constructor is what I thought would be an empty constructor. However, how I've added what you said Der Golem, I get the error in the edit above ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem lies in the AndroidManifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".Bike"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

you are declaring `Bike` as activity, but Bike is not extending `Activity`. The fun fact is that you are not getting a *compile time error* as one would have expected, but a *run-time crash*, which tells you that the class is being instating a run time trough reflection. To fix it either let Bike extends Activity (and get rid of the constructor) or remove it from the Manifest. Please be aware that using the `new` operator on a class that extends `Activity` is a bad practice

Comment: How would I fix this?

Comment: That certainly is a fun fact orb

Comment: it is orb, because it looks like a compile time error but is a run time error @codeMagic. The mystery of reflection

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed response, however I've added extends Activity and it's still giving me the no empty constructor error, despite having an empty constructor

Comment: get rid of the constructor.

Comment: I've tried that, however I then get errors in my UseCustomerAdapter.java class which states "The constructor Bike(String, String) is undefined"

Comment: UseCustomAdapter.java** has been added in

Comment: in this case you should have followed the or case. You are using Bike as bean-class for your adapter. Revert that changes in Bike, remove it from the AndroidManifest file, and put  UseCustomAdapter in its place. Btw, try to follow some naming convention. It the class extends activity then call it NameClassActivity

Comment: Thankyou bud! Sorted it now, very efficiently answered